# Facebook Account SMS integration failed on Android

Tags: android, facebook

Facebook `Account kit` sms integration didn't work.
When I used code from github it works and send sms through already integrated account in this App.
https://github.com/fbsamples/account-kit-samples-for-android/tree/master/samples/AccountKitSimpleSample

But when i Create App at `Facebook account kit`, copy `Client Token` and `App Id`. then it didn't work.
"A system issue occurred. Please try again" error occurred
How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Check this - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you did not  enable `Enable client access token flow` in Facebook Developers panel.

Go to : Developer [page](https://developers.facebook.com/)

After login Select your app - > go to : Products-> Account Kit

[image]

Now enable the permission:

[image]

Comment: @AAhmadBlal you should mark the answer as correct..thnkx